# weak_ptr obtained from weak_from_this() is invalid

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

Here is a minimal example to reproduce:

source code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
 public:
  A(std::weak_ptr<A> up) : up_(up)
  {
    std::cout << "A" << " has up_? " <<
        ((up_.lock()) ? "yes" : "no")
              << std::endl;
  }

  void grow()
  {
    if (dp_)
      dp_->grow();
    else
      dp_ = std::make_shared<A>(weak_from_this());
  }

 private:
  std::weak_ptr<A> up_;
  std::shared_ptr<A> dp_;
};

int main()
{
  auto wp = std::weak_ptr<A>();
  A a(wp);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    a.grow();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

original log:

```
clang++ minimal.cpp && ./a.out
A has up_? no
A has up_? no
A has up_? yes
A has up_? yes
```

desired behavior:

```
clang++ minimal.cpp && ./a.out
A has up_? no
A has up_? yes
A has up_? yes
A has up_? yes
```

Actually I want to know why the second line in the original output says 'no'? I think when we create the object of type A for the first time, (precisely after its construction finishes, and before we call `grow()` on it), we have a valid object that we can pass references to to wherever we want, don't we?

Comment: Inheriting from `std::enable_shared_from_this` is a promise that every `A` is owned by a `std::shared_ptr<A>`. You break that promise

Comment: @Caleth source?

Comment: @Fureeish "It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr<T>`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined" [enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). C++ doesn't *enforce* the liskov substitution principle, but it's a very useful guideline.

Comment: @Caleth I believe when you combine `C++` and phrases like "*you break that promise*", you either have to be **technically** correct (according to the rules of the standard), or you're not correct at all. I get what you're trying to say, but in principle, there's nothing wrong with having an `A` object that's unmanaged any any `std::shared_ptr`s, as long as you don't call the methods that require that as the preconditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From cppreference, about [`std::enable_shared_from_this::weak_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this)

> Returns a `std::weak_ptr<T>` that tracks ownership of `*this` by all existing `std::shared_ptr` that refer to `*this`.

Meanwhile

```
A a(wp);
```

This is not an object that is tracked by any `shared_ptr`. It's a plain object with automatic storage duration. If you want `weak_from_this` to work, there must be a `shared_ptr` tracking the first object.